# Dialogflow - TIMEOUT_DNSLOOKUP on webhook execution

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm facing a pretty strange issue on Dialogflow's fulfillment.

**Context:**

- I made a simple Dialogflow bot with some fulfillment intents. Those intents are working as expected when I test them in my development environment (using ngrok tunneling service to generate a publicly accessible `https` endpoint for my webhook server).
- After this, I've started facing a problem in my pre-production server. The architecture in this last server is exactly the same as in development. The fact is that the intents are working correctly most of the time but **sometimes** the same intents are not working; more concretely, the bot is not answering at all.

**The error:**

- Taking a look to my Dialogflow history, I've noticed a shared error between all the "non-responded" messages which is as follows:

[image: Error in Dialogflow history]

**It seems that the DNS Lookup process that is making Dialogflow sometimes ends up in a timeout error.**

I'm adding a diagram to add more context:

[image: Communication diagram]

I've tested the availability of my domain by making a stress test with over 50k calls to my fulfillment endpoint checking:

- Response status code is 200.
- Call resolves before 5 seconds (Dialogflow's max timeout on webhook calls).

All those calls passed the test.

The fact that the intents are failing **sometimes** (more times working than failing) is driving me crazy... I'd appreciate any clue on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mochis, Can you give more details such as the versioning of the Dialogflow library you are using? Also, are the messages hitting in parallel? ( if so there are some quotas that might be surpassing (CX and ES agent), you can check it [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/quotas#es-agent_1) .

Comment: Hi @Betjens, I'm not using any Dialogflow library in terms of code. I'm using the current version of Dialogflow ES. It also does not seem to be problem of my quota usage, since i'm testing the bot alone and no one is interacting with it besides of me. As a reminder, the bot is working correctly when I use ngrok tunneling to serve my webhook backend.

Comment: Its hard to reproduce your error scenario. Also it looks like its more on NGNIX side of your flow, I would like to know more about your NGNIX setup. Also, [see](https://serverfault.com/questions/240476/how-to-force-nginx-to-resolve-dns-of-a-dynamic-hostname-everytime-when-doing-p/593003#593003)

Comment: Note that my **NGINX is not receiving any call when this error happens**. Anyway, I'll tell you more about my NGINX. I have just configured it to listen for 443 ssl, setup the hostname and certificate (+ key) and enabled 2 proxy_pass (/chat and /api). Related to the thread you referred, I'm using docker-compose to orchestrate the deployment so I use service names to configure the proxy_pass. In addition, I guess if it was NGINX fault I would see any NGINX log which I don't.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Everything was working ok until three days ago ( I didn't change anything). Using DialogFlow ES, sometimes the problem appears. I don't know what is happening.

I have the fulfillment inside in a VM in a GCP project

```
  "diagnosticInfo": {
    "webhook_latency_ms": 1226
  },
  "webhookStatus": {
    "webhookStatus": {
      "code": 4,
      "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, State: URL_TIMEOUT, Reason: TIMEOUT_DNSLOOKUP."
    },
    "webhookUsed": true
  },
```

Comment: Could it be a problem on the google side?

Comment: Hi Bruno. Indeed, this seems to be a problem on Google side but I'm not 100% sure. Could you share more about your scenario? Lets see if we can find common points and solve this.

Comment: Hi Mochics. I have two different projects in GCP, both are completely isolated. Each project consists of a VM deployed in GCP, and inside the VM there are multiple dockers for different purposes, I use docker-compose too. In one docker I have a NodeJs server that calls the dialogflow API, in the same docker I have the fulfillment server (webhook calls). Last Friday everything was working ok, in both projects. I didn't change anything and the problem started between Friday and Monday. I suppose that something change in DialogFlow or in the DNS server.

Comment: What is the DNS provider you are using for production?

Comment: I'm not sure about the DNS provider since I'm not the owner of the domain. Could ask if it is super relevant.

Comment: Hi Bruno. Here you have the link to the issue I've recently opened in the Issue Tracker of Dialogflow. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/203461124. You can star the issue to show you're affected by it. Google uses it to prioritize its solution.

Comment: Thanks, Mochics. I created an internal case for regional support. I'm waiting for the Google response.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there were some updates on DialogflowES in the last days, check
[DialogFlowES Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/release-notes).

Maybe you should raise this directly to Google [Issue Report](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) and they can provide further assistance.

Comment: Hi Betjens, I see no related releases in the last months but I'll submit the issue to the Issue Tracker you linked. Thanks.

Comment: I've opened the issue in the Issue Tracker of Dialogflow. Fingers crossed. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/203461124